# Testing client/server in gTest

Tags: c++, googletest, googlemock

I'm trying to write tests for my chat program based on client/server interaction. After reading some sources I came up with idea of using Google Mock but the whole concept seems a little bit abstract to me. Let's say I want to test client. In order to do that, should i write a server mock that imitates the work of an actual server or I got something wrong?

Comment: It's a little unclear. What is the question here?

Comment: I want to test client. I'm asking in what way should I do it? Like what would be the approach to do that. Should I mock server class? Would it imitate the network?

Comment: First decide what you are going to test and what constitutes a pass. Then decide how you are going to test it. Asking how to use gTest on a chat client in general is a bit too broad, so you really want to ask a question with a specific test or family of tests in mind. Ultimately you will need to test both with and without a mocked server. Mocking the server would mean you aren't really talking to the server, a good thing to do if you don't trust the server yet, but leaves out testing some of the bits and bobs that are very likely to go wrong.

Comment: Can you give an example of a function you would want to test so we can help with an example?

Comment: @mkamerath Yeah, sure! For example I have function in client that sends a string to server and it sends it back. So after sending a line I should expect getting same line in the client.

Comment: Can you add it as code in your example? I'm also going to edit the question to be a little more specific

Comment: https://github.com/mikolajkucinski/Instant-messenger Inside develop branch, there is current code